# Php Getting matching vaues from multidimensional arrays based on column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having 2 multidimensional arrays on php, and I'm trying to get only the subarrays that have matching column value.

1st Array :

```php
0 => {#1 ▼
    +"name": "John Doe"
    +"education": "Finance"
    +"age": "23"
    +"mark": "10"
  }
1 => {#2 ▼
    +"name": "Jane Doe"
    +"education": "History"
    +"age": "25"
    +"mark": "9"
  }
2 => {#3 ▼
    +"name": "Anne Smith"
    +"education": "Computer Science"
    +"age": "22"
    +"mark": "8"
  }
```

2nd Array :

```php
0 => {#1 ▼
    +"name": "Bob Builder"
    +"country": "US"
    +"city": "Massachusetts"
  }
1 => {#2 ▼
    +"name": "Jane Doe"
    +"country": "France"
    +"city": "Paris"
  }
2 => {#3 ▼
    +"name": "Anne Smith"
    +"country": "Germany"
    +"city": "Berlin"
  }
```

I want to match on column `name`.

Desired output should be as follows :

```php
0 => {#2 ▼
    +"name": "Jane Doe"
    +"country": "France"
    +"city": "Paris"
    +"education": "History"
    +"age": "25"
    +"mark": "9"
  }
1 => {#3 ▼
    +"name": "Anne Smith"
    +"country": "Germany"
    +"city": "Berlin"
    +"education": "Computer Science"
    +"age": "22"
    +"mark": "8"
  }
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

First, reindex the first array by name. This will simplify matching names in the next part.

```
$first = array_column($first, null, 'name');
```

Then iterate the second array. If the person exists in the first array, merge the values from the two arrays and append that to the product. If not, don't do anything, since you're only looking for the intersection.

```
foreach ($second as $person) {
    if (isset($first[$person['name']])) {
        $product[] = array_merge($first[$person['name']], $person);
    }        
}
```

One potential problem with this is that names aren't unique, and this will break if you ever have any people with the same name. It would be much better if you had some unique identifier to use for a person rather than name.

Comment: This solution works fine for me, thanks ! I'm taking into consideration that the column I'm going to merge on should be unique.